# python PIL Image open isn't RGB

Tags: python-imaging-library

i've been trying to open a .jpg image using

```
im = Image.open('file.jpg').
```

my problem is that for some reason the "im" is not an RGB image, i.e the channels are not R,G,B. this also cause the `im.convert('L')` (rgb2gray) give a very bad result.

[channel 0 image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMJof.png),
[attemped gray sacale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXTIs.jpg).

Im using: Python 2.7.12 |Anaconda 4.1.1 (64-bit)

I would very much appreciate any help figuring this out.

**edit**:
it seems the problem is that the matplotlib color map isn't set right. does anyone know why? and how to fix?

Answer (score 13):

You can find current mode in `im.mode` and do convert with `im.convert('RGB')`.